# Man in the middle server

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle

At my school, the server (only internet available) uses a MITM attack at all times, on all computers. We also lose access to most VPN's because of this. Is there any method to avoid this without using another server? Is there a VPN made specifically for this?

Comment: By passing your school's protections is not on topic here. Product surveys of what VPNs can do certain things are also off-topic.